# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.struts.config.ModuleConfig.findActionConfigId(Ljava/lang/String;)

Tags: jsp, struts-1, web-deployment-project

i build a war with maven, and when running the war through url facing this error:500 even thought the method exists in jar. In dev environment application is running fine but facing problem with deployed war. using  struts-core 1.3.10 jar

Answer (score 0):

verify the generated war file that it has the correct library file. I faced the same issue and was able to resolve after placing the jar file.